# Как отправить файл сразу в объектное хранилище cURL PHP?

Tags: php, php-curl

С формы файл загружается на сервер(ajax), после заливается в объектное хранилище Selectel(PUT cURL php).
Подскажите, можно ли избежать загрузки файла на промежуточный сервер и загружать файл с формы сразу cURL'ом в хранилище?
Спасибо!

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.selcdn.ru/v1/SEL_1337/test/Eprtst1.mp4",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('
' => new CURLFILE('test/upload/5ec46a241e58b.mp4')),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "X-Auth-Token: 478493248"
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать NGINX с проксированием запроса, указав необходимые заголовки и настроив его соответствующим ссылке образом, то можно это сделать как указано [тут](https://serverfault.com/questions/768693/nginx-how-to-completely-disable-request-body-buffering)

Пример:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass                      http://получатель-файла/;
        proxy_redirect                  off;
        proxy_buffering                 off;
        proxy_request_buffering         off;
        allow                           all;
        proxy_http_version              1.1;

        proxy_set_header                Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header                X-Auth-Token 478493248
        client_body_buffer_size         0;
        client_max_body_size            0;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size        0;
        proxy_read_timeout              18000;
        proxy_send_timeout              18000;

        gzip                            off;
}
```

И соответственно настроки сервера:

```
client_max_body_size 0;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_request_buffering off;
```

Которые по сути должны быть не нужны так как эти параметры уже есть выше.